# How to apply a function that contains multiple regression on 2 by 2 variables in df by category in R?

Tags: r, function, regression, apply, lapply

My df is somthing like this:

```
ind1 <- rnorm(99)
ind2 <- rnorm(99)
ind3 <- rnorm(99)
ind4 <- rnorm(99)
ind5 <- rnorm(99)
dep <- rnorm(99, mean=ind1)
group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=33)
df <- data.frame(dep, group, ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5)
```

This is a function that combines different types of regression equations.

```
functions <- function(x, y) {
  eq1 <- lm(dep ~ x + y)
  eq2 <- lm(dep ~ I(x*y))
  eq3 <- lm(log(dep) ~ I(log(x+1)^2) + I(log(y+1)^2))
  list <- list(eq1, eq2, eq3)
  names(list) <- paste0("mod", 1:3)
  return(list)
}
```

Then I applied this function to ind1 and ind2 variables by group as below.

```
out <- lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) functions(x$ind1, x$ind2))
lapply(out, summary)
```

But there is a error saying that variable lengths differ (found for 'x')? So how I can fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the issue is that the formula needs the column names instead of the values

```
functions <- function(dat, x, y) {

   form1 <- paste0("dep ~ ", x, " + ", y)
   form2 <- paste0("dep ~ ", "I(", x, "*", y, ")")
   form3 <- paste0("log(dep) ~", "I(log(", x, "+1)^2) + I(log(", y, "+1)^2)")
    eq1 <- lm(form1, data = dat)
    eq2 <-  lm(form2, data = dat)
    eq3 <- lm(form3, data = dat)
    list1 <- list(eq1, eq2, eq3)
    names(list1) <- paste0("mod", 1:3)
    return(list1)

}



out <- lapply(split(df, df$group), function(x) functions(x,  "ind1",  "ind2"))
```

Also, as the output is a nested `list`, we may need to get inside the inner `list` to extract the `summary`

```
lapply(out, function(x) lapply(x, summary))
```

Comment: thank you! in this case, it says "Error in functions(x, "ind1", "ind2") : unused argument ("ind2")".

Comment: @SunRise  Sorry, I am not getting the error.  Are you using the same example in your post

Comment: Thank you! I am using my original data. how should I handle NANS in this formula?

Comment: @SunRise  DId you meant `NA`s

Comment: yes! it is NA s. the values of my original data are less than 1. when they take log, they become even more lower values, sometimes minus values.To solve this, I added 1 to x & y but there is still problem with it